# E1740 lambda captured variable of type "..." cannot be copied to closure class field of type "..."

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, c++-cli

I have recently installed VS 2019 and opened up my project I created in VS 2017. The software works fine but there is a bug in VS with lambda captured variables. MS apparently is aware of said issue, but I was wondering if anyone else had come across this recently and if you have, have you managed to solve it?

Example bit of code from my project, the intellisense has flagged up every line where "[this]" appears. The error / bug reads

> lambda captured variable of type "MainPage^*" cannot be copied to closure class field of type "MainPage^"

```
if (_serialPort1 != nullptr)
{
    concurrency::create_task(WriteToSerialDeviceAsync(cancellationTokenSource_serialPort1->get_token(),
        Arduino_Device.Outgoing_Bytes, PORT_1)).then([this](concurrency::task<void> previousTask) {
        try
        {
            previousTask.get();
        }

        catch (Platform::COMException^ ex)
        {
            this->DataStreamWindow->Text += "\r\n!EXCEPTION CAUGHT! " + ex->Message;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please check your .csproject if everything is adjusted with target version. Is it just related to intellisense? Does it build without any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I managed to stumble upon a somewhat ugly hack to fix this.

Rather than pass `[this]` into the lambda, I added the line `auto _this = this;` prior to creating any tasks. This did however mean that any variables which were accessed using `this->SomeVariable` became `_this->SomeVariable`.

So my example above now looks like this.

```
if (_serialPort1 != nullptr)
{

auto _this = this;

concurrency::create_task(WriteToSerialDeviceAsync(cancellationTokenSource_serialPort1->get_token(),
    Arduino_Device.Outgoing_Bytes, PORT_1)).then([_this](concurrency::task<void> previousTask) {
    try
    {
        previousTask.get();
    }

    catch (Platform::COMException^ ex)
    {
        _this->DataStreamWindow->Text += "\r\n!EXCEPTION CAUGHT! " + ex->Message;
    }
});
```

}

Hope this is of use.

Answer (score 1):

If so then why copying outside the task? You could do

```
if (_serialPort1 != nullptr)
{   concurrency::create_task(WriteToSerialDeviceAsync(cancellationTokenSource_serialPort1->get_token(),
        Arduino_Device.Outgoing_Bytes, PORT_1)).then([_this = this](concurrency::task<void> previousTask) {
        try
        {
            previousTask.get();
        }
        catch (Platform::COMException^ ex)
        {
            _this->DataStreamWindow->Text += "\r\n!EXCEPTION CAUGHT! " + ex->Message;
        }
    });
}
```

But based on your problem this is not the proper solution. You better find what's wrong with your project migration to VS 2019.

Comment: There is an open issue on the VS developer forum. It does seem like a VS bug.

Comment: So I have just changed the platform toolset to VS 2019 in the properties dialog and it VS then went on to suggest various includes and namespaces that should be added to project. Various variable types were now flagged as errors. After all that,  I reverted the code back to [this] and removed the line auto _this = this; And, lo and behold everything is now working again.